# Multiple tabs not working with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

[This is the pen](http://codepen.io/mohammadhamza/pen/esKCD) I'm working on and the Jqueryis below.As I want a tab style like each button shows the desire content.

**Jquery**

```
$('.content-canvas').find('div').hide();
$('.content-canvas div:first-child').show();
$('.tab-button span:first-child').addClass('active');
$('.tab-button').find('span').click(function(){
  $('.tab-button').find('span').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var currentclass=$('.active').attr('class');
 $('.content-canvas').find('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('class')==currentclass)
    {
      $('.content-canvas').find('div').hide();
      $(this).show();
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).hide();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Why not using the Jquery Tab Control ? http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: It is because using of that much heavy script will decrease the page rank,as I can't do that for the sake of the multiple tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are missing dot in front of class `active`

   ```
   var currentclass = $('.active').attr('class');
   ```
2. Also, if you do `alert(currentclass)` it will show you that it says something like "content2 active". Probably not what you expect. You could go with `data-name="content2"`. And then you select with:

   ```
   var currentname = $('.tab-button .active').data('name');
   $('.content-canvas [data-name="'+currentname+'"]').show().siblings().hide();
   ```